# Is Ubuntu Gnome lighter than original Ubuntu flavor?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I'm trying to install linux dual boot on my mac. I'm am looking for something light, and I noticed the original Ubuntu flavor has a lot of add-ons. So my question is, is Ubuntu Gnome lighter?

Comment: If you are really looking for a lighter version, see Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the 'standard' variant of Ubuntu was using the Unity desktop environment and Ubuntu Gnome was one of the official flavors sponsored/recognized by Canonical.

I do not have the usage stats handy but use Ubuntu Gnome as the sole OS on a MacBook Air (2014 mode year) and like it very much.  Gnome is, if I remember correctly, is lighter than the standard Ubuntu running the Unity DE but heavier than Lubuntu and Xubuntu.  The Gnome DE is very responsive and looks great on my machine.  The install was pain-free and fast as well.  Lubuntu and Xubuntu will both work and I used each for about 2 weeks each then installed Ubuntu Gnome.  I found Gnome to better suit my workflow and personally like it better.  Another option for you may be Ubuntu Mate.  I have run that on a couple PC's and was impressed by the speed, low resource usage, and looks.

I recently bought 5 refurbished MacBook Air 13" and installed Zorin OS and gave them to kids and grand-kids for back to school gifts.  It is a little heavy on resources but is based on Ubuntu with a modified Gnome DE.  Very good looking distro and is familiar to ex-Windows users.

Answer (score 1):

"standard" Ubuntu is the GNOME version.  There's Xubuntu (XFCE), Kubuntu (KDE), and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (lightweight).

This only affects the initial set of packages that gets installed.  After install, you just have an Ubuntu system configured to start one or the other graphical desktop by default.  Kubuntu for example installs the [`kubuntu-desktop` meta-package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/kubuntu-desktop) (which exists only to depend on and recommend other packages). Just plain Ubuntu has [`ubuntu-desktop` installed out of the box](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-desktop), which depends a bunch of gnome packages, like `unity` (a gnome window manager), `nautilus` (the gnome file manage), and the `lightdm` login manager.  Plus many other things.

All the Ubuntu flavors install [`ubuntu-standard`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-standard) and [`ubuntu-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-minimal) to give you a bootable and usable GNU/Linux system underneath whatever graphical desktop they launch by default.

With a decent package manager like `aptitude`, it's not a life-or-death decision which flavour to install.  (ncurses text UI, great interaction with dependencies and keeping track of packages that were only installed to satisfy deps, not because you requested them directly.)

You can have hours of fun learning about Debian package dependencies and conflicts, and desktop login config files and crap, if you decide to purge `ubuntu-desktop` and install something else...  :)  It's supposed to work, and probably does, but something confusing for a brand-new user may crop up.